# Javascript - How to frozen selection values from dropdown list after click button

Tags: javascript

How can we forzen a dropdown list to be selected after click a button.
For example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Submit</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

After select a value from dropdown list and clicked 'submit' button, how to prevent further selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using jQuery

---

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  $('#mySelect').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Submit</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

## Or using JavaScript

---

```js
document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('mySelect').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

## In case you have multiple `select`'s

---

```js
var selected = '';
$('select').each(function(index, sel) {
  $(this).change(function() {
    selected += $(this).prop('id') + "#";
  });
});

$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  var res = selected.split("#");
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    $('#' + res[i]).prop('disabled', true);
  }
  selected = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="sel1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel2">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel3">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn">Submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that's fabulous! however, If I have more than 1 dropdown list with same id name, it will not block the first dropdown list. Anyway to solve this issue? rather than just changing the id names as I have around 20 dropdown lists.

Comment: The `id` global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS). Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Comment: @user3651247 please check my updated answer. Let me know if it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add disabled attribute to select on button click

```
<select id="ddlTest" disabled="disabled">


$("#btnClick").click(function () {
   $("#ddlTest").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of `Submit`, call a method which set the disabled attribute to select. I have given an id `selectMe` to the select element so as to uniquely fetch it in javascript.

```js
function foo() {
  var selectElem = document.getElementById('selectMe');
  selectElem.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="selectMe">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="foo()">Submit</button> 
</body>
</html>
```